# Should i extend the child component when passing the rest props from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would like to know what is the best practice and why, when it comes to typing the rest props in a component. I usually try to extend the composed component props but the issue is not all props are possible and i always have to omit some of them which can become ugly very quickly.

Here is an example to explain the issue:

```
export default function TenantPopover({
  loading,
  tenants,
  selected,
  disabled,
  onChange,
  ...props
}: TenantPopoverProps) {

  return (
    <Popover
      className="TenantPopover"
      disabled={disabled || tenants?.length < 2 || !tenants}
      {...props}
    >
      <Button onClick={onChange} />
    </Popover>
  )
}
```

Should i extend the Popover so that the rest props is typed like this?:

```
interface TenantPopoverProps extends Omit<ComponentProps<typeof Popover>, 'onChange' | 'children'> {
  loading?: boolean;
  tenants: Tenant[];
  selected: Tenant['id'][];
  disabled?: boolean;
  onChange: (tenants: Tenant['id'][]) => void;
```

Or should i keep the rest props untyped (will have "any" type which mean you can pass anything to the component)?

```
interface TenantPopoverProps {
  loading?: boolean;
  tenants: Tenant[];
  selected: Tenant['id'][];
  disabled?: boolean;
  onChange: (tenants: Tenant['id'][]) => void;
```

or is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: What usually do you pass in the `rest`?

Comment: By rest i mean `...props` 
I usually pass additional popover props

Comment: Yea, but do you already know what they will be? Or do you have any plan to release this codebase as a library that allows for any value to be passed as props? If you already know all and only the props you will be passing into the component, my approach would be to make it as strict as possible.

Comment: I do know the props that will be used and I kinda like your idea of making things as strict as possible. 

The problem is that doing this means every time i need to add new prop to the component, I have to manually add it. The autocomplete becomes useless as well.

I guess the developer experience has to suffer for the sake of type safety here.

Comment: Yes I do agree that this may make your dev experience a bit worse at initial development, but the future-you will thank you for the maintainability. I usually skip between files to make sure the components are as strict as possible, one more benefit it also brings is the efficient communication within your team as we can talk via the type signature without the need to actually looking inside the functions to see what parameter it takes